# How do I not borrow an Option when matching?

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```
fn remove_descendent(&mut self, key: &K) -> Option<V> {
    if self.left.is_some() && self.left.as_ref().unwrap().key == *key {
        return self.remove_left();
    }

    // more of the function
}
```

This feels gross to me. Instead of checking `is_some` and then unwrapping. I figured what I really should be doing is using a match statement to deconstruct the `Option` represented by the `left` variable like so:

```
fn remove_descendent(&mut self, key: &K) -> Option<V> {
    match self.left {
        Some(ref left) if left.key == *key => self.remove_left(),
        _ => None
    }
```

However, when I do this I get the following error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because `self.left.0` is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/lib.rs:29:51
   |
29 |             Some(ref left) if left.key == *key => self.remove_left(),
   |                  --------                         ^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
   |                  |
   |                  immutable borrow occurs here
30 |             _ => None
31 |         }
   |         - immutable borrow ends here
```

I guess I get that I can't immutably borrow a structs member and then mutably borrow the struct. But if that's the case, what's the proper way to pattern match my `Option`? Is there one?

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at the [if let](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/if-let.html) Syntax?

Comment: @hellow `if let` does not support [Guards](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.5.0/book/patterns.html#guards).

Answer (score 3):

The compiler complains because in the match arm `self` is still borrowed. You can get around this with cloning the `key` beforehand:

```
fn remove_descendent(&mut self, key: &K) -> Option<V> {
    match self.left.clone() {
        Some(ref left) if left.key == *key => self.remove_left(),
        _ => None,
    }
}
```

You can see this in action [on the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9afdcccd1904dd186acf63194210a409&version=stable&mode=debug).

With [*Non Lexical Lifetimes*](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-roadmap/issues/16) enabled, your code compiles just fine: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=03109b8cfcb6bd8dad88b4be283a6c88&version=nightly&mode=debug).

Comment: is cloning really what I want to do here? It seems like I shouldn't have to. Can't clones be expensive?