# What is the difference between `Some(&a) => a` and `Some(a) => *a` when matching an Option?

Tags: rust, borrowing

Why does this pass:

```
fn f(v: Vec<isize>) -> (Vec<isize>, isize) {
    match v.get(0) {
        Some(&a) => (v, a),
        _ => (v, 0)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5e4b4cfd5dad133e15dec9017400303d&version=stable&mode=debug)

but this doesn't?:

```
fn f(v: Vec<isize>) -> (Vec<isize>, isize) {
    match v.get(0) {
        Some(a) => (v, *a),
        _ => (v, 0)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2bd2672afffe4df5c7b063c10f69356f&version=stable&mode=debug)

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `v` because it is borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:7:21
  |
6 |     match v.get(0) {
  |           - borrow of `v` occurs here
7 |         Some(a) => (v, *a),
  |                     ^ move out of `v` occurs here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`v.get(0)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.get) returns a reference to the element in the vector, so you are matching `&isize`. The `Vec` is now borrowed in the match arm.

In the first code snippet, you copy the `isize`, so the `Vec` isn't borrowed here. In the second snippet, the `Vec` is still borrowed, so you cannot move it out of scope.

However, you should consider to use `if let` or `unwrap_or`:

```
fn f(v: Vec<isize>) -> (Vec<isize>, isize) {
    let a = v.get(0).cloned();
    (v, a.unwrap_or(0))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7afbee2a24f78dfcacb08f17fcce897e&version=stable&mode=debug)

```
fn f(v: Vec<isize>) -> (Vec<isize>, isize) {
    if let Some(&a) = v.get(0) {
        (v, a)
    } else {
        (v, 0)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dbd1b4231eaf2323590fdc7c900ba8e7&version=stable&mode=debug)

---

See also:

- [How do I not borrow an Option when matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50752778/how-do-i-not-borrow-an-option-when-matching)
- [How do I borrow a reference to what is inside an Option<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282117/how-do-i-borrow-a-reference-to-what-is-inside-an-optiont)
- [Cannot move out of borrowed content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158738/cannot-move-out-of-borrowed-content)

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet, when you type `Some(&a)`, you do not borrow `v` because `a` is copied.

In the second case, `Some(a)` is of type `Option<&isize>` so it holds a reference to `v`. When you try to move it, it triggers an error. If you copy it first, and then you return the pair, it works (you need the [NLL feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-roadmap/issues/16) however):

```
#![feature(nll)]

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", f(vec![1]))
}

fn f(v: Vec<isize>) -> (Vec<isize>, isize) {
    match v.get(0) {
        Some(a) => {
            let a = *a; // v is no more borrowed
            (v, a)
        },
        _ => (v, 0)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=73be9cea8e1d1d947b5e694bc23f62d9&version=nightly&mode=debug)

The borrow checker cannot be perfect, so you will often encounter some slightly inconsistent stuff.